# Проверка данных не правильно работает

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите разобраться
Использую вот такой простейший код:

> if( !preg_match("/^[a-zа-я]{3,15}/iu", $name)) echo 'Имя указано не
>   корректно.';

Проверка не регистрирует когда $name имеет следующие значения:

> $name 'testname testname'; $name 'testnametestnametestnametestname';

Когда есть пробел или больше 15 символов...
Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался)
Вот так сделал

> if( !preg_match("/^[a-zа-я]{3,15}+$/ui", $name)

Comment: Знак плюса тут не имеет смысла. Сформулируйте свой вопрос правильно, так как сейчас не понятно, что вам надо: то ли пробелы нужно пропускать и строки длиннее 15 символов, то ли не нужно.

Comment: Изначальная проверка пропускает строку от 3х до 15 знаков из букв латинского/русского алфавита. Никаких посторонних символов и длинных строк. То есть работает именно так, как нужно.

Comment: @iosp, там не все буквы русского алфавита как всегда.

Comment: Все правильно, проверка должна пропускать от 3х до 15 символов русского и латинского алфавитов в UTF-8 кодировке, без учета регистра.

Comment: Когда добавил +$ тогда заработало как должно.

Comment: @Юрий, я еще раз повторяю: плюс тут не нужен! Регулярка должна выгдядеть так: `/^[a-zа-яё]{3,15}$/iu` P.S. Букву `Ё` забывать не надо.

Comment: Понятно на счет + ), просто там помимо знака + еще $ добавил, он и помог получается. За пример спасибо!

Comment: А можете еще подсказать как если возможно сделать данной проверке что бы она пропускала только только русские или латинские символы. К примеру если ввести 'nameимя' что бы не пропускало...

Comment: Можно так сделать:
if( !preg_match("/^[a-z]{3,15}$/iu", $name) || !preg_match("/^[а-яё]{3,15}$/iu", $name) )
но хотелось бы одним выражением...

Comment: @Юрий: Добавьте это условие в вопрос. Можно и одним выражением.

Answer (score 0):

В исходном выражении `^[a-zа-я]{3,15}` отсутствует знак конца строки `$`, поэтому регулярное выражение проверяет наличие указанных букв только в начале строки. Кроме того, стоит добавить модификатор `D` (`PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY`).

Так как было добавлено условие на проверку только латинских и только русских букв, необходимо разделить `[a-zа-я]{3,15}` на 2 класса - `[a-z]{3,15}` и `[а-яё]{3,15}` и объединить их с помощью оператора `|` и подмаски `(....)` (или `(?:...)`)

```
$names = array("Имя", "Name", "Nameимя", "НифигаСебеИмечко");
foreach($names as $name) {
  if( !preg_match("/^(?:[a-z]{3,15}|[а-яё]{3,15})$/Diu", $name)) {
      echo "Имя $name указано не корректно.\n";
    } else {
      echo "Имя $name указано корректно.\n";
  }
}
```

[См. демо](https://ideone.com/SJU8oX)